# ASP.NET Core Identity 2.0 SignoutAsync is not logging out user if the user signed in with Google

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

I have Asp.net Core Identity version 2.0 Set up and running.  I am finding that `_signinManager.SignoutAsync` is not logging out user once they have signed in with Google.  When I go back to my Login Method it just shows the User as logged in with their Claims object still intact.

The code is really simple as below

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult TestGoogle()
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalCallback), "Account", new { ReturnUrl = "" });
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties("Google", redirectUrl);
    return Challenge(properties, "Google");
}


public async Task<IActionResult> LogOff()
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
}
```

Comment: Hi, maybe is the cookie. Try it in you LogOff:

await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("yourcookie");

Comment: Looked at this answer but VS says that method is obsolete and will be removed in future version.  So want to avoid.

Answer (score 21):

The problem is that your `RedirectToAction` overwrites the redirect to the Identity Server endsession URL that `SignOutAsync` issues.

As for `SignOutAsync`, what is obsolete is the `Authentication` portion -- as of ASP.NET Core 2.0 it's an extension directly off `HttpContext` itself.

(The same explanation for the same signout problem is given [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/313#issuecomment-120668602) by Microsoft's HaoK.)

Edit: The solution is to send a redirect URL in an `AuthenticationProperties` object with the final `SignOutAsync`:

```cs
// in some controller/handler, notice the "bare" Task return value
public async Task LogoutAction()
{
    // SomeOtherPage is where we redirect to after signout
    await MyCustomSignOut("/SomeOtherPage");
}

// probably in some utility service
public async Task MyCustomSignOut(string redirectUri)
{
    // inject the HttpContextAccessor to get "context"
    await context.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
    var prop = new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
        RedirectUri = redirectUri
    };
    // after signout this will redirect to your provided target
    await context.SignOutAsync("oidc", prop);
}
```

Comment: Who downvoted and why? I have this code running in production, and I have encountered the same issue in the question. I'm as sure it's correct as I can be given the details provided by the question. Looks like a drive-by downvote to me.

Comment: May upvotes rain upon you! I can only give you the one though. I was doing the same SignOutAsync then RedirectToAction and getting sad about why it wouldn't work. This was the perferct fix for me.

Comment: When using with WS-Federation, I had to replace the second sign out with `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("WsFederation", prop);`

Comment: I am getting error an error - "No sign-out authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'oidc'.

Comment: why oidc not cookies

await context.SignOutAsync("oidc", prop);

Comment: @nil96 The "Cookies" part addresses what ASP.NET is tracking, the "oidc" part goes back to the auth server and tells it that a signout occurred -- and provides the correct redirect URI once the auth server is done. Most people (like the answer below) only do the ASP.NET part and the auth server doesn't know about the signout.

Comment: @McGuireV10 thanks.I am getting this error "No sign-out authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'oidc'. Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 4):

Just the first line solved my issue.

```cs
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
await _SignInManager.SignOutAsync();
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.Cookies");
```

Comment: `await _SignInManager.SignOutAsync();` was enough for me. It deletes the _.AspNetCore.Identity.Application_ cookie.

Comment: So glad this was posted. I also had to code to delete the cookie.