# SignOutAsync is not working for microsoft authentication in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I've created a ASP.NET Core MVC application with microsoft authentication.  here, I'm using following code to signout the user account.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> LogoutAsync()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

but, user account still signed in. what's the problem?. Is there any possibilities to signout the account completely including microsoft web sites.

I have already tried following code from this[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131517/asp-net-core-identity-2-0-signoutasync-is-not-logging-out-user-if-the-user-signe)

```
public async Task LogoutAsync()
    {
        await SignOut("Home/Index");
    }


    public async Task SignOut(string redirectUri)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
        var prop = new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            RedirectUri = redirectUri
        };
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Microsoft", prop);
    }
```

it still signedin click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UN1P.png) to check it.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131517/asp-net-core-identity-2-0-signoutasync-is-not-logging-out-user-if-the-user-signe