# Unable to invalidate the Asp.Net cookies instantly after logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

User has logged out from the Site but APIs are accessible from POSTMAN with cookies in the header? 
[image]

Logout

```
        public async Task OnPost(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = returnUrl
            });

        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.Cookies");
    }
```

Startup

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        HostingEnvironment = env;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Https
        services.AddHsts(options =>
        {
            options.Preload = true;
            options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
            options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(180);
            options.ExcludedHosts.Add("admission.just.edu.bd");
            options.ExcludedHosts.Add("www.admission.just.edu.bd");
        });

        services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
        {
            options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
            options.HttpsPort = HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() ? 5001 : 443;
        });

        services.AddMemoryCache();

        services.AddDbContext<AdmissionDbContext>(options =>
        {
            if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DbConnection:Sql:Local"], x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable("__EFMigrationsHistory", Configuration["DbConnection:Sql:Schema"]));
            }
            else
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DbConnection:Sql:Cloud"], x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable("__EFMigrationsHistory", Configuration["DbConnection:Sql:Schema"]));
            }

        });

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(
            options =>
            {
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AdmissionDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthorization(opts =>
        {
            opts.AddPolicy("AuthenticatedUser", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());
            opts.AddPolicy("SystemAdminOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole(SystemRole.Administrator));
            opts.AddPolicy("SupportOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole(SystemRole.Support));
            opts.AddPolicy("ApplicantOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole(SystemRole.Applicant));
        });

        services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformation>();

        services.AddSession();

        services.AddMvc(
                options =>
                {
                    options.Filters.Add<ErrorExceptionFilter>();
                }
            ).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.AllowAreas = true;
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
            })
            .AddJsonOptions(opts =>
            {
                opts.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                opts.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
                opts.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                opts.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                opts.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;

                if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    opts.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                }
            });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseHsts();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRequestLocalization();

        // app.UsePendingMigrations();

        app.UseDefaultRoles(SystemRole.All);
        app.UseDefaultUsers();

        //app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("areaRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no logout code in the question. Even if `Response.Cookies.Delete(cookieKey);` deleted the cookie (it doesn't, it removes it from the *response*), that won't prevent POSTMAN or any other client from *sending* the cookie again

Comment: It has `await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();`

Comment: Please post only the *relevant* code.

Comment: all right. I have edited my code. Can you please help now?

Comment: You removed the relevant parts - that `LocalRedirect` and left the configuration which isn't relevant. It's the redirection that sends the actual response and cookies. I suspect this is a duplicate of [ASP.NET Core Identity 2.0 SignoutAsync is not logging out user if the user signed in with Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131517/asp-net-core-identity-2-0-signoutasync-is-not-logging-out-user-if-the-user-signe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core Identity 2.0 SignoutAsync is not logging out user if the user signed in with Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131517/asp-net-core-identity-2-0-signoutasync-is-not-logging-out-user-if-the-user-signe)

Comment: Hi, it did not solve. I have updated the logout code. Still, I am able to send requests from POSTMAN

Comment: It's not a duplicate question. Please undo your close vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but for some reason `Response.Cookies.Delete(cookieKey)` was not working for me. What I did was create another cookie with the same cookie name with expiry set to a time in past. Eg:

```
var c = new HttpCookie("cookieKey");
c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(c);
```