# SigninManager.SignOutAsync() Not Working in IIS Express After VS Update

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-express, asp.net-core-identity

My ASP.Net Core MVC project has been working fine for the past two years or so.  It basically uses the Login/Logout code that is generated by the Visual Studio template from that time.  My logout code looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
}
```

I noticed yesterday that this code does not actually log me out anymore - it redirects me to the home page, but the login link says "User Portal" instead of "Log In" as expected, and I can navigate to restricted pages.  `_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User);` returns true in my Razor views.

After researching and trying things for several hours, I tried publishing to my IIS staging server, and the code still works as expected once it is published to IIS.  It seems to fail only while I am debugging in Visual Studio using IIS Express.  It is worth noting that I just updated to version 16.5.1 around the time that it broke, so I suspect that it has something to do with this version of VS.  I can't remember what version I was on before, but it was probably a few months old.

I have tried the ideas in the following links without success:

[ASP.NET Core Identity 2.0 SignoutAsync is not logging out user if the user signed in with Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131517/asp-net-core-identity-2-0-signoutasync-is-not-logging-out-user-if-the-user-signe)

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6439

https://mcguirev10.com/2018/01/26/signoutasync-and-identity-server-cookies.html

(Long story short on the links: the following change does not help:)

```
// does not work
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, new AuthenticationProperties
{
    RedirectUri = "/Home/Index"
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  This is completely derailing me because I log in and out frequently to test different user permissions...

Comment: Also, comparing the working published version to the broken debugging version using the network tab in Google Chrome's developer tools, the files requested look identical in both.

Comment: similar behavior in 2022 on Duende with `AddJwtBearerClientAuthentication`